# using setTimeout freezes browser

Tags: javascript

So I just ran into this issue here and thought I'd share it, knowing probably others will run into this same problem too.

I was using setTimeout in my script to create a loop, for example:

```
function myExample() {
    //Do Something
    setTimeout(myExample(), 3000);
}

myExample();
```

And suddenly, my page started freezing up, loading would take forever, until chrome finally decided to stop the tab's process.

Comment: you shouldn't invoke it when passing as a callback.

Comment: I added this as a Q & A style thing, in the hope it would help others, assuming it would automatically accept my own answer too. apparently not

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem here was something which can be easily overlooked.

```
setTimeout(myExample(), 3000);
```

instead of

```
setTimeout(myExample, 3000);
```

this was causing it to call the function right away, looping itself without any delay whatsoever. add a XHR request to each function call, et voila. a browser-tab crash.

I can't guarantee this is what is causing your problem, but this was something that I didn't notice after quite a long time.